# JavaScript simplify for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I built the following for Loop and wanted to ask if there is a way to simplify it:

```
//data contains an array
var i = 0;
if(data.length >= 1) {
    i = 1;
}
for (i; i <= data.length; i++) {
    $('#img-thumb-id' + i).attr('src', data[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: You can use `$.each`. And always start loop index from zero.

Comment: Do i understand right that you want it to be displayed once if data.length == 0? It doesn't appear to work in that case ..

Comment: @Adder i think that was an attempt to also check if data is empty

Answer (score 3):

I see that jQuery is used here, so you can use `$.each`

```
$.each(data, function(i, item){

   var iteration = +i+1;
   $('#img-thumb-id' + iteration).attr('src', item);

});
```

if you want to use vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery at all)

```
for (var i; i < data.length; i++) {
   var iteration = +i+1;
   document.getElementById('img-thumb-id'+iteration).src = data[i];
}
```

Or you can use:

```
for (var i in data) {
   document.getElementById('img-thumb-id'+(+i+1)).src = data[i];
}
```

Comment: If you want to offer  a vanilla solution might I suggest you replace `$('#img-thumb-id' + iteration)` with `document.getElementById('img-thumb-id'+iteration)` I know the OP is using a jQuery selector but for future visitors it could be misleading or confusing as they will be expecting vanilla only.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof data!=="undefined" && data && data.length>0) {
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#img-thumb-id' + (i+1)).attr('src', data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if(data && data.length) is equal to your condition

Comment: @Jonasw please check this example, it is not equal https://jsfiddle.net/ftr46syd/1/

Comment: @Jonasw `if(typeof data!=="undefined" && data && data.length)` and `typeof data!=="undefined" && data && data.length>0` perform better.

Comment: @Jonasw yes it perform better check the fiddle, do not define `data` and check the output, do the same for `data` being `null,"",[],{}` you will see some differences, to sum up this is more fail safe `typeof data!=="undefined" && data && data.length` i think if you really had the time to check the fiddle you would agree on that. Best regards.

Comment: @Jonasw and in addition in case you would like to mimic `PHP's` `empty` function what would you think of something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ftr46syd/2/ ?

Comment: @peter darmis NO! it will work the same except the case {length:true} however, thats very unlikely...

Comment: @peter darmis phps empty does return false for these cases  "", 0, 0.0, "0",NULL,FALSE,array(). All these values are falsy except [] and "0". so the correct implementation would be empty=v=>(v && (v.length!=0 || parseInt(v));

Comment: @Jonasw in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ftr46syd/1/ if you don't define `data` you get an error at `if(data && data.length)` `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined` but in this case `if(typeof data!=="undefined" && data && data.length>0)` and in this case `if(typeof data!=="undefined" && data && data.length)` you get an alert as expected.

Comment: @Jonasw this is a straight-forward example https://jsfiddle.net/ftr46syd/1/ and no this `if(data && data.length)` is not the same with this `if(typeof data!=="undefined" && data && data.length)`. You may write it as you want but you want avoid the error thrown (fiddle explains it but you don't like it)

Comment: @peter darwin the OP clearly says that data is an array, so why do you check for non existence? and event then: var data; if(data && data.length) or if(window.data && data.length)

Comment: @Jonasw yes yes whatever...! But this `if(data && data.length)` will fail to an error if undefined. And yes the OP declared that `data` is an array but i see no harm in checking if it is empty or even an undefined variable.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is fine, but I don't see why you don't just do:

```
if(data !== null){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#img-thumb-id' + (i + 1)).attr('src', data[i]);
            }
}
```

You don't need to do the first block of code in your question. It is more clear to people reading your code if you just do a standard for-loop starting from 0 and going up to the object.length.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this :

```
data.forEach(function(item, index){
   $('#img-thumb-id' + (index+1)).attr('src', item);
});
```

Comment: be careful with `'#img-thumb-id' + index+1` ...won't produce what you expect

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl placed index+1 inside parenthesis

Answer (score -1):

> Use simple foreach loop in JavaScript

```
//for eg. data array may be
var data = [1,2,3,4];
data.forEach(function(item, index){
$('#img-thumb-id' + (index+1)).attr('src', item);
});
```

Comment: iteration is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, for the undefined the index is used

Comment: @downvoter please remove your downvote, tue answer is now valid